# PHP подскажите правильно ли я понял MVC паттерн

Tags: php, mvc

Здравствуйте, подскажите правильно ли я понял концепцию MVC паттерна.

1.В Роутер получает GET запрос. Там он обрабатывает GET запрос, подключая нужные файлы контроллера, модели и view, в нашем случае это новости (пример - https://site.ru/news/123)

```
class Router {

private $routes = array(
    'news' => array('newsbyid','newsbycategory'), 
    'products');
public $url;

function __construct() {
    $this->url = explode('/', trim($_GET['uri'], '/'));
}

public function run() {

    if(!empty($this->url)) {
        if(in_array($controller = $this->url[0], array_keys($this->routes))) {

        require_once rootdir.'/models/'.$controller.'model.php';
        require_once rootdir.'/controllers/'.$controller.'controller.php';

        switch (count($this->url)) {
            case 1:
                $action = $this->url[0];
                break;

            case 2:
                $action = $this->routes[$this->url[0]][0];
                $arg = $this->url[1];
                break;  

            case 3:
                //
                break;
        }
            call_user_func_array(array($newscontroller, $action), array($arg));
            require_once rootdir.'/views/'.$controller.'/view.php';
    }

        else return '404 not found';
    }

        else return 'Main page';
    }
```

}

В Newscontroller вызывается метод получения данных новости

```
class Newscontroller extends Newsmodel {

public $news = array();

public function news() {
    $this->news = $this->getnews();

}

public function newsbyid($id) {
    $this->news = $this->getnewsbyid($id);
}

public function newsbycategory($category) {

}
```

}

$newscontroller = new Newscontroller;

Мы берем этот список новостей у модели, класс который наследуем

```
<?php

    class Newsmodel {

        public function getnews() {
            $count = 2;
            for ($i=0; $i <$count ; $i++) { 
                $news[$i]['id'] = $i;
                $news[$i]['title'] = 'title'.$i;
                $news[$i]['message'] = 'message'.$i;

            }
            return $news;
        }

        public function getnewsbycategory($category) {

        }

        public function getnewsbyid() {
                $news[0]['id'] = 1;
                $news[0]['title'] = 'title';
                $news[0]['message'] = 'message';
                return $news;
        }
    }

    $newsmodel = new Newsmodel;
```

Данные получены и обработаны, и в свойстве класса новостей находится сама новость.  Теперь в роутере (см. сверху) идёт `require_once rootdir.'/views/'.$controller.'/view.php';`

```
<?php foreach ($newscontroller->news as $news):?>
<b><?php echo $news['title']?></b>
<div style="font-size: 15px; border: 1px solid red;"><?php echo $news['message'] ?></div>
<br><br>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

И получается сам метод роутера `run()` вызывается в `index.php ($router->run()` и пользователь видит новость

**Спасибо всем кто не поленился и прочитал до конца.**

То есть если быть кратким.

1.От пользователя поступает GET запрос.
2.Роутер отбирает нужный тип контроллера.
3.Контроллер обращается к модели получает данные к примеру из бд
4.А в файле view находится html разметка в которой собственно и будут выведены эти данные

Comment: `Контроллер обращается к модели`...... да, контроллер может обращаться к модели, а у тебя контроллер наследуется от модели - что неверно

Comment: Вот представь, есть ShopController, в котором нужно вывести из какой-то категории продуктов сами продукты ну и, допустим, что-то из их детального описания.  В итоге будет три модели Productcategories - чтобы понять есть ли там чо, Products и Productmedias.... как наследовать ShopController от трех моделей?))) в общем контроллеры должны наследоваться от какого-нибудь общего Controller, но никак не от моделей

Comment: В самом конце вашего вопроса всё описано правильно. Но вот код, который вы создаете, противоречит этому. Посмотрите как устроены популярные фреймворки на php (yii, laravel, symfony, zend).